# How will HQL(hibernate query language) need to change if we use @embedded annotataion?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

spring mvc + hibernate
I have two one table which contains user data.
now I want to make two class.
1. user
2. address -> because we can use it into many places.
and we have has-a relationship on that.

```
@Embedded
class Address
```

and

```
class user
{
@Autowired
Address address;
}
```

is it a good idea or bad?

due to this can I have to change in hibernate query?

Answer (score 2):

It is good idea to implement has-a relationship.

create class Address with Embeddable annotation to define common column(properties)

```
@Embeddable
class Address{
    String city;    
    String state;
}
```

use in User class has-a relationship

```
public class User {
    @Embedded
    private Address address;
}
```

You can query it like:

```
session.createQuery( "select u from User u where u.address.city=:city" ).setParameter( "city", 'ahmedabad' ).list();
```

or:

```
    session.createQuery( "select u from User u where u.address.city in (:city)" ).setParameterList( "city", Arrays.asList( 'surat', 'ahmedabad' ) ).list();
```